# fire event on adding a character-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload a page when I type a character into a textbox and after reload, take cursor back to the `textbox.` It (browser) should not reload when I delete a character from the textbox.

I was trying this but it doesn't work

```
$('#id_BasePairs').bind('input', function() { 
location.reload();
 $('textbox').focus();
 });
```

How should it be done?

Comment: see if you press some key page reloads then how you are able to delete the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `$('textbox').focus();` in `$(document).ready` and it will be focused when the page is reloaded.

Then change your key press event to this:
It reloads the page as long as the inputted key was not `backspace` or `del`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#textbox').focus();

     $('#textbox').keyup(function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46) {
             location.reload();
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: still reloading when I hit backspace or delete even if I change && to ||. I get undefined in the console when I alert(e.keyCode);. not 8 or 46

Comment: Wow! its working now! Thanks a lot. I guess if I want to exclude other keys, I will add their codes with '&&' between them?

Comment: Yeah you can add as many as you like, just add `&& e.keyCode != 'code'` :) Enjoy!

Comment: A list of codes can be found [Here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: Thanks again! for the assistance. +1 everywhere :)

Answer (score 2):

use keyup function to check the typed character.. check for keycode 8 and 46 for delete and backspace and if not reload... you have to focus the input before reloading.. since codes after reload won't be called....

```
 $(function(){
 $('#inputId').focus();
 $('#inputId').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46)
     { 
        location.reload();
     }
 });

});
```

Comment: It is still reloading when I hit backspace or delete. when I put alert here ...function(e){alert(e.keycode); if(e.keycode != 8 ||...., it alerts undefined in the console. what could be the issue?

Comment: The issue is that he uses "||"  (or) in the if statement instead of "&&"  (and).  See other answer.

Comment: @AlexKasina yes.. i updated my answer it should be &&... try it out

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy has a fatal error

```
location.reload();
// all the code from now on is irrelevant as the page reloads.
...
...
```